# in iphone is there any alternate way of CLLocation to find location

Tags: iphone

I am not getting accuracy by using CLLocation

```
CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:CurrentUserLocationNow.latitude longitude:CurrentUserLocationNow.longitude];

locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:newLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:newLocation.coordinate.longitude];

distance = [locA distanceFromLocation:locB];

int feet = distance*3.28084;

if(feet >= 40)
{
    [avaudioplayer stop];
}
```

but I am not getting perfect accuracy

Comment: please elaborate your question. What issues you are facing ?

Comment: I mean is there any alternate way to find location in iphone without CLLocation

Comment: you wont be able to get "perfect" accuracy using CLLocation, but it is the class you need to work with

Comment: Yes I am working on 5 days I got the answer what I need but is not accurate

Answer (score 0):

`CLLocation` class method `distanceFromLocation` is the easiest way to find the distance between two points on map. Talking about your accuracy that you can set with the help of your `CLLocationManager`  desiredAccuracy property to `kCLLocationAccuracyBest`.
But if you  using the [google direction api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) in your project you can do from by parsing the json.(Hectic task)

Comment: Yes I understand but I mean is there any alternate way to find location without CLLocation in iphone

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in iOS to garner location without using CLLocation. There may be 3rd party libraries that allow you to get location, but they would all just be wrappers for CLLocation. Apple does not allow access to the GPS hardware any other way. So if you need location, you are basically stuck with CLLocation.